# How do I can say Laravel that if the thread belongs to this user, allow him to edit or delete the thread?

Tags: php, database, laravel, authentication

well my headline pretty much says everything I need. I'm building a little website for me, just to learn the laravel framework. I created a login/register and some functions to do a thread or to delete/edit the thread. My current problem is, that it doesn't matter if the user who is logged in, is the same who wrote a thread. Just the fact that the user is logged in, allows him to edit or delete every single thread on my webpage. Thats of course not like it should be... Thats why I like to get the realation that says: If the user who is logged in, have some threads, then allow him to delete or to edit his own threads. If the user isn't the one who wrote the thread, then don't show him the option to delete or to edit the thread at all.

now this is my current HTML -- or better a snipped of it:

```
   @if( Auth::check())
        <div class="panel-footer">
            {!! Former::horizontal_open()->method('DELETE')->action(action("Test\\TestController@destroy", $thread->id))->id('conf') !!}
            {!! Former::danger_submit('Delete') !!}
            {!! Former::close() !!}

            <a href="{{ URL::route('edit', $thread->id) }}">
            <div class="btn btn-primary">Edit</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    @endif
    </div>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="btn pull-right"><a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@index') }}">Go back</a></div>
    </a>
```

So this just check if the user is logged in, if not, he don't see the edit / delete button. If he is logged in, of course he see them.

Now I need a code to say if he is the same who wrote the thread, then allow him to edit/delete it.

Well, I really don't know how I can do this and I haven't really found something for this..

I have two models. One for all the threads and one for all the users.

I did a 'belongsTo' realation in my thread model, and said that it belongs to the  name attribute in my user table.

Thread Model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\Thread;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thread extends Model {
    public $table = 'thread';
    public $fillable = [
        'thread',
        'content',
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "name");
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\Thread;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {
    public $table = 'users';
    public $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];
}
```

well.. I'm stuck, I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks for any help and support

Other Code parts my can help:

```
Route::get('/show/{id}', 'Test\\TestController@show');
Route::get('/show/{id}/edit', 'Test\\TestController@edit')->name('edit');
Route::put('/show/{id}/edit', ['as' => 'editing', 'uses' => 'Test\\TestController@update']);
Route::delete('/show/{id}', 'Test\\TestController@destroy')->name('destroy');
```

thats all the route I have to show just the thread, or to delete/edit the thread

Controller: that is the show function that gives me the view with the buttons:

```
  public function show($id)
    {
        $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);
        return view('test.show', [
            'thread' => $thread,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#defining-abilities

Comment: well, I see the point and understand most of it but I'm more like a laravel beginner so can't imagine where I can start now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Laravel's [ability](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#defining-abilities) system.

Or when editing your thread in the controller you could do something like this:

```
$thread = Thread::findOrFail($thread_id);

if (!Auth::check() &&
    $thread->user()->first()->id != Auth::user()->id) {
    abort(404); // Stop the user
} else {
    // Edit the threat
}
```

**EDIT TO YOUR EDIT:**

Does this work out for you?

```
public function show($id)
{
    $thread = Thread::findOrFail($id);

    if (!Auth::check() &&
        $thread->user()->first()->id != Auth::user()->id) {
        abort(404); // Stop the user
    }

    return view('test.show', [
        'thread' => $thread,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I will try your code out :) the only thing I don't understand is the ->first() part.. what is this for? 

I really would like to use laravel's ability system but I don't really understand it :/ I see at it and of course understand what it means to do, but I can't figure out where I start etc...

Comment: @ItzMe488 You could try `$thread->user->id` to, that's basically the same.

Comment: okay.. tried that but haven't worked.. I think I did some things wrong.. I didn't know where I shoud put the code. I will update my question with my show function. My show function shows the page where the delete/edit button are. So if you klick on a thread ( in a list of threads I have ), then you will get direct to the show route -> show function, and the function directs you to the HTML with the buttons etc... I will update my question with some things couse I don't really know how to put the code right. -- btw, I did a thread_id attribute to my Database.

Comment: I can't really test it because I'm getting an: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Test\Auth' not found exception.

Comment: add this at the top of the file but under the namespace: `Use Auth;`

Comment: Okay I tried it out but it still the same. I tried it with 3 different accounts and everyone was allowed to edit or delete any threads :/

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way of doing what you want is using the **Request class**. You just need to create a new Request:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

 /** Remember to include here the classes you are using, 
  *  in your case it would be something like this:
  */
use App\Models\Thread;
use Auth;

class EditThreadRequest extends Request {
   /**
    * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
    *
    * @return bool
    */
    public function authorize()
    {
      /**
        * You can get the thread id from your view
        * using for example a hidden input
        * {!! Form::hidden('id', $thread->id) !!}
        */
      $thread = Thread::findOrFail($this->get('id'));
      return $thread->user->id === Auth::user()->id;
    }

   /**
    * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function rules()
    {
      return [
         // Your validation rules
      ];
    }
}
```

The above function will return true in case that thread belongs to that user, allowing the user to continue with the request.

After this you just need to include the freshly created request in your edit function like this and it will automatically check if user can edit the thread:

```
public function edit (EditThreadRequest $request)
{
  // Your code
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm just asking if I got this right. I will do a request file ( named for exampe EditThreadRequest and put there the code you gave me. After that I will edit my edit function ( and the delete function too right ) with :  -------------    public function edit (EditThreadRequest $request, $id )  { ... }  ( and the same for delete function ) ---- right?

Comment: That´s right, You should create a new request everytime you have to create/edit something: CreateThreadRequest, EditThreadRequest... This way you can validate your input fields and authorize/not authorize that request. You can create a new request through the command line like this: php artisan make:request EditThreadRequest.

Comment: I tried it but it gives me a : Class App\Http\Requests\Auth\EditThreadRequest does not exist -- And of course I did a :  use App\Http\Requests\Auth\EditThreadRequest;

Comment: Why did you include \Auth\ in your path? Your path should be use App\Http\Requests\EditThreadRequest;

Comment: cause I did a Auth dictionary before the php class file -- I will change it and try again

Comment: Okay I moved it in another dictionary but it still the same.. at the top of Controller: use App\Http\Requests\EditThreadRequest; ------- and in my function:  public function edit(EditThreadRequest $request, $id)

Comment: Ok, check that EditThreadRequest is in the right path and also check EditThreadRequest file and be sure that the name of the class is correct and also you followed the code I wrote above. If you are still getting an error show it to me.

Comment: okay the name of my class in the file: EditThreadRequest.php ( copy & paste ). At the top of my Controller is written: ----- use App\Http\Requests\EditThreadRequest; ( Copy & Paste ). The File is defenetly in the Requests dictionary. The error I get: Class App\Http\Requests\EditThreadRequest does not exist

Comment: The error you are getting is App\Http\Requests\ThreadRequest does not exist. So ThreadRequest is missing the word Edit at the beginning. Now you just need to find where you wrote ThreadRequest instead of EditThreadRequest, possibly in your edit function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104656/discussion-between-diego-vidal-and-itzme488).